# How to solve Type error: Argument 1 passed to Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\EloquentRepository::findWhereNotIn() must be of the type array?

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query is like this :

```
$this->user_repository->findWhereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

When executed, there exist error like this :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Type
>   error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\EloquentRepository::findWhereNotIn()
>   must be of the type array, string given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\app\Console\Commands\Check.php
>   on line 48

Whereas in the tutorial https://github.com/rinvex/repository#findwherenotin, it looks like my query is correct

How can I solve it?

Comment: `Argument 1` refers to `id` not being an array

Comment: try to use  `['id']` instead

Comment: @Onix, It does not work. There exist error : `[ErrorException]
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @Machavity, I change like this : `$this->user_repository->findWhereNotIn(['id'], [1, 2, 3, 4]);`, but it does not work

Comment: Shouldn't it be `whereNotIn` instead of `findWhereNotIn` ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Comment: @Michael Kunst, I use rinvex repository. So `whereNotIn` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing column name as string in first parameter, then values as an array in second parameter, while the correct syntax for `rinvex/repository` **findWhereNotIn** [as per the docs](https://github.com/rinvex/repository/tree/develop#findwherenotin) is passing both column name and values to the first parameter as an assosiative array as follows:

```
$repository->findWhereNotIn(['id', [1, 2, 5, 8]]);
```

Notice how they're passes: **['id', [1, 2, 5, 8]]**

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326809/how-to-solve-missing-argument-3-for-rinvex-repository-repositories-baserepositor