# How to solve Missing argument 3 for Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\BaseRepository::join()?

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use this : https://github.com/rinvex/repository

My query is like this :

```
$query = $this->store_repository
    ->join('favorites', function ($join) {
        $join->on('stores.id', '=', 'favorites.favoritable_id')
            ->where('favorites.favoritable_type', 'like', 'App\\\Models\\\Store');
    })
    ->where('stores.status', '=', 1)
    ->select('stores.id', 'stores.name', 'stores.photo','stores.address');

if($location)
    $query->where('stores.address', 'like', "%$location%");

if($q) {
    $query->where('stores.name', 'like', "%$q%")
        ->where('stores.address', 'like', "%$q%", 'or');
}

$result = $query->orderBy('favorites.updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($num);
```

When executed, there exist error like this :

> Missing argument 3 for
>   Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\BaseRepository::join()

How can I solve it?

Comment: Add the missing argument.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions, Where the missing argument?

Comment: I can't find anything in that git repo docs about a `join()` method. Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: after the closure `->join('favorites', function($join){/*..*/},$missingArg)`, i have tryed to find out what that missing arg is, but its hard, it seems that `join` is defined in `illuminate` and not in `rinvex/repository` see the `use` statemants in `BaseRepository` and for `join` is `_call()` executed. where a `$model` is called. @Joe you have to dig to find it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the clojure to make what you want.

I guess this should be fine :

```
$query = $this->store_repository
    ->join('favorites', '=', 'favorites.favoritable_id')
    ->where('favorites.favoritable_type', 'like', 'App\\\Models\\\Store');
    ->where('stores.status', '=', 1)
    ->select('stores.id', 'stores.name', 'stores.photo','stores.address');
```